# First menu item default dark grey in W3.CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

[image: The first menu item is dark grey on page entry]

As you can see in the picture, the first menu item is defaulting to dark grey even though I have not specified this anywhere.I think this means it is active even when no mouseover.

Desired behaviour: Entire menu bar is light grey unless mouseover

W3 schools says:

> Navigation Bar with Dropdown
>   Note: When the dropdown menu is "open", the dropdown link gets a grey background color to indicate that it is active. To override this, add a w3-hover-color class to both the "dropdown" li and a:

Here is my html code

```html
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-light-grey  w3-border">
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 0</a>

 <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>
  

 </div></li>
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 1</a>

 <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>
  

 </div></li>
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 2</a>

 <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>
  

 </div></li>
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 3</a>

 <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>
  

 </div></li>
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 4</a>

 <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
  <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>
  

 </div></li>

</ul>
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Would you be able to share your css with us as well?

Comment: Did you try to fix through 'inspect element' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3.css file is setting that using the following css, notice the .w3-dropdown-hover:first-child.

```
.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover:hover,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-hover:first-child,.w3-sidenav .w3-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
```

*Added by original poster:*

Simply changing the background-color to light grey (#f2f2f2) works, but it seems to be a bit of a hack as this forces all navbars on the site to share the color.
However, this may be a flaw in w3c as I honestly don't see another solution. So I accept this one

Comment: OK, but not quite sure how to edit out of the css. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hacking core css is not best solution, as i posted in my answer adding a simple w3-light-grey class solves the problem

Comment: This was bugging me also, I will just say this particular code (html and css) from W3 was not designed to work the way you want it to with just dropdown items (one or more).  It was really meant to be navigation items with some that have dropdown(s). Further more it seems that the dropdown can't be the first item in the list.  The exception here is if you switch it to "click" dropdown instead of "hover" dropdown.  One further thing IMHO the W3.css packs too much stuff in there for a good learning example...you would be much better off rolling your own or finding a better example.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar and the hover have the same color so i dont understand how you can get a visible hover color change. nevertheless just give first list items a w3-light-grey class and this will solve your issue, giving your desired output.

```
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-light-grey  w3-border">
                    <li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-light-grey w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 0</a>

                        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>


                        </div></li>
                    <li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 1</a>

                        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>


                        </div></li>
                    <li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 2</a>

                        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>


                        </div></li>
                    <li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 3</a>

                        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>


                        </div></li>
                    <li class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-light-grey"><a class="w3-hover-light-grey" href="http://www.google.com">Item Name 4</a>

                        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 0</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 1</a>
                            <a href="www.i-koda.com">link name 2</a>


                        </div></li>

                </ul>
```

Updated code and fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eyjqrh85/1/

Comment: I want everything light grey, no dark grey

Comment: just change w3-hover-dark-grey with w3-hover-light-grey. In your question you asked: Desired behaviour: Entire menu bar is light grey unless mouseover. If the navbar and the hover have the same color how can you achieve that? anyways updated answer code and fiddle.
adding those classes is a better solution to changing the core css since it would only apply where you need it.